# remove if else in java

Tags: java, if-statement

How can I change this if else statement to something more elegant

```
public void setAttributes(List<UserAttribute> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;

    for (UserAttribute attribute : attributes) {

      if (attribute.getName().equals(SERVICE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL_ID)) {
        featureCode = attribute.getValue();
      } else if (attribute.getName().equals(ATTRIBUTE_DESKTOP_USED)) {
        quotaUsage = new BigInteger(attribute.getValue());
      } else if (StringUtils.equals(ATTRIBUTE_INSERTION_TIME, attribute.getName())) {
        insertTime = transformLongToDateSafely(Long.parseLong(attribute.getValue()), MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
      } else if (StringUtils.equals(ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVED_TIME, attribute.getName())) {
        archivedTime = transformLongToDateSafely(Long.parseLong(attribute.getValue()), MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
      } else if (StringUtils.equals(ATTRIBUTE_LAST_MODIFIED_TIME, attribute.getName())) {
        lastModifiedTime = transformLongToDateSafely(Long.parseLong(attribute.getValue()), MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
      } else if (StringUtils.equals(CUSTOM_EXTERNAL_ID_1, attribute.getName())) {
        dvQuotaUsage = attribute.getValue();
      } else if (StringUtils.equals(CUSTOM_EXTERNAL_ID_2, attribute.getName())) {
        mmQuotaUsage = attribute.getValue();
      } else if (StringUtils.equals(LAST_LOGIN_ACCESS_MOBILE, attribute.getName())) {
        lastMobileLogin = DateUtils.transformDateFormatSafely(attribute.getValue(), EEE_MMM_d_HHmmss_zzz_yyyy, MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
      } else if (StringUtils.equals(LAST_LOGIN_ACCESS_PC, attribute.getName())) {
        lastPCLogin = DateUtils.transformDateFormatSafely(attribute.getValue(), EEE_MMM_d_HHmmss_zzz_yyyy, MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
      } else if (StringUtils.equals(LAST_LOGIN_ACCESS_WEB, attribute.getName())) {
        lastWebLogin = DateUtils.transformDateFormatSafely(attribute.getValue(), EEE_MMM_d_HHmmss_zzz_yyyy, MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
      } else if (StringUtils.equals(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION, attribute.getName())) {
        dcLocator = attribute.getValue();
      }
}
}
```

Sonar complains cognitive complexity because of the multiple if else statement. How can I make this simple and better.

Comment: Questions about optimizing running code is better asked at [codereview.se]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: if you post on Code Review please read the help center pages like [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - in its current form this post would be considered off-topic because there is little context about what the code does and how the function is used, plus the title is about modifying the code for readability (a CR goal) instead of describing what the code does

Comment: @BasilBourque in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Then you should remove "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" from the list of reasons to close a Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque [there was an attempt to do this in 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289949/1575353) - sadly it was not well received 

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like  `switch` `case` is what you are looking for:

```
public void setAttributes(List<UserAttribute> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;

        for (UserAttribute attribute : attributes) {
    
          switch(attribute.getName()){
              case SERVICE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL_ID:
                 featureCode = attribute.getValue();
                 break:
              case ATTRIBUTE_DESKTOP_USED:
                 quotaUsage = new BigInteger(attribute.getValue());
                 break;
              case ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVED_TIME:
                 archivedTime = transformLongToDateSafely(Long.parseLong(attribute.getValue()), MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
                 break;
              case ATTRIBUTE_LAST_MODIFIED_TIME:  
                 lastModifiedTime = transformLongToDateSafely(Long.parseLong(attribute.getValue()), MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
                 break;
              case CUSTOM_EXTERNAL_ID_1:  
                  dvQuotaUsage = attribute.getValue();
                  break;
              case CUSTOM_EXTERNAL_ID_2:
                  mmQuotaUsage = attribute.getValue();
                  break;
              case LAST_LOGIN_ACCESS_MOBILE:                
                  lastMobileLogin = DateUtils.transformDateFormatSafely(attribute.getValue(), EEE_MMM_d_HHmmss_zzz_yyyy, MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
                  break; 
             case LAST_LOGIN_ACCESS_PC: 
                  lastPCLogin = DateUtils.transformDateFormatSafely(attribute.getValue(), EEE_MMM_d_HHmmss_zzz_yyyy, MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
                  break;
             case LAST_LOGIN_ACCESS_WEB: 
                  lastWebLogin = DateUtils.transformDateFormatSafely(attribute.getValue(), EEE_MMM_d_HHmmss_zzz_yyyy, MM_dd_yyyy_HHmm, UTC);
                  break;
             case ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION:
                  dcLocator = attribute.getValue();
                  break;
             default:
               //what to do if the attribute name is unhandled until now
          }
    }
}
```